# Using a for loop to repeat concentric ellipses

Tags: javascript, processing

This is my first time posting here, bear with me as I might mess up the formatting. With the code below, I am trying to get the 2 overlapping/concentric ellipses to repeat a random number of times (in this case I chose 1 through 20) around random places on the 400x400 canvas. I've tried many different things but what keeps happening is the concentric ellipses become scattered and it becomes a mess of color and unrecognizable shapes. **The fill must stay within the outside loop and the drawing inside the nested loop.**

```js
noStroke();

var flower = function(){ 

for(var total = 5; total > 0; total--){

    fill(random(0,255),random(0,255), random(0,255));

    
    
    for(var i = 0; i < random(1,20); i++) {
    
        
    ellipse(200, 200, total * 10, total * 20);

    ellipse(200, 200, total * 20, total * 10);
}
}
};
flower();
```

For reference below, I did something similar except I did it with a while loop and used circles. The same thing needs to happen to my concentric ellipses. I've been trying to follow the same procedures I did with the while loop assignment.

```
var i = 0;

var circle = function(x,y) {
    while (i< random (1, 20)){
        stroke(random(0,255),random(0,255), random(0,255));
        strokeWeight(random(0,50));
        point(random(x,y), random(x,y));
        i++;
}


};
draw = function() {
        circle(0,400);
    };
```

I feel like I am getting kind of close with this..

```js
noStroke();

var flower = function(x,y){ 

for(var total = 5; total > 0; total--){

    fill(random(0,255),random(0,255), random(0,255));

    
    
    for(var i = 200; i < random(205, 300); i++) {
    
        
    ellipse(i + random(x,y), i + random(x,y), total * 10, total * 20);

    ellipse(i + random(x,y), i + random(x,y), total * 20, total * 10);
}
}
};
flower(5, 150);
```

This one feels a little closer.. Just need to keep the concentric ellipses together.

```js
noStroke();

var flower = function(x,y){ 

for(var total = 4; total > 0; total--){

    fill(random(0,255),random(0,255), random(0,255));

    
    
    for(var i = 0; i < random(1,20); i++) {
    
        
    ellipse(i + random(x,y), i + random(x,y), total * 10, total * 20);

    ellipse(i + random(x,y), i + random(x,y), total * 20, total * 10);
}
}
};
flower(0, 400);
```

Comment: you could always use the code snippet tool, that makes your life easier in terms of formatting. just click on the [<>] icon on the tool bar to update your code blocks.

Comment: Question.. why wont the code snippet run? I am doing all this over khanacademy because that's where our instructor want's us to do our assignments if that effects anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to draw both of the circles in the same place each time?

If so, then look at how you're drawing your circles:

```
  ellipse(i + random(x, y), i + random(x, y), total * 10, total * 20);
  ellipse(i + random(x, y), i + random(x, y), total * 20, total * 10);
```

You're calling `random(x, y)` a total of **four times** to come up with random coordinates **for each circle**. This will cause them to be drawn in different places. If you want to draw them in the same place, then you should only call `random(x,y)` a total of **two times** (once for the X position and once for the Y position) and then use those values for both circles. Something like this:

```
  var circleX = random(x, y);
  var circleY = random(x, y);

  ellipse(circleX, circleY, total * 10, total * 20);
  ellipse(circleX, circleY, total * 20, total * 10);
```

If this doesn't answer your question then please try to be more specific. Maybe post a mockup of what you want the end result to look like, and try to narrow down the problem to a specific line of code that isn't acting how you expected it to.

Comment: Thank you. This wasn't exactly what I am looking for but it definitely pushed the program in the right direction. I had  to turn in the assignment as is so hopefully the instructor gives me feedback. The only real problem I am having is keep the concentric detail.

Comment: @Smokeyflo Can you please be more specific about exactly what you mean by concentric detail? Maybe post a mockup of what you want the end result to look like.

Comment: Here is the original code (sorry dont have time right now to figure out how to properly format code during a comment): `noStroke();

 

for(var total = 25; total > 0; total--){

    fill(random(0,255),random(0,255), random(0,255));

    ellipse(200, 200, total * 10, total * 20);

    ellipse(200, 200, total * 20, total * 10);

}`

Comment: The directions are as follows: 
    1. It will draw a random number of the image.
    2. Use a nested for loop such that the fill is in the outside loop and the drawing is in the inside loop. Use appropriate values.

Comment: What I mean by concentric detail is the "rainbow" effect

Comment: @Smokeyflo You can't properly format code in a comment. If you have a follow-up question, please post it as a new question in its own post.

Answer (score 0):

A simple single for loop should suffice to draw concentric circles.

In your code you do a couple of things that end up being random ellipses rather than concentric circles:

1. use the same diameter to render an ellipse as a circle: `ellipse(i + random(x,y), i + random(x,y), total * 10, total * 20);` will always be en ellipse.
2. use the same centre for to draw ellipses to keep them **con**centric(same-centre)

For example:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  noStroke();
  background(255);

  
  var x = 200;
  var y = 200;
  //number of circles
  var circles = 9;
  //for each circle
  for (var total = 0; total < circles; total++) {
    //compute circle diameter based on reverse index (circles-total) (or max-current)
    var diameter = (circles-total) * 30;
    fill(total * 30);
    //render the circle
    ellipse(x,y, diameter, diameter);
    
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

To get a rainbow effect, you can use [colorMode()](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/colorMode) to swith to the `HSB` (hue-saturation-brightness) colour space. This way you simply need to use an increasing hue value. You can even constrain the number of hues.

Here's a demo (mouseX changes the number of circles/hues)

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  noStroke();
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  var x = 200;
  var y = 200;
  //number of circles
  var circles = map(mouseX,0,width,7,21);
  //change the color mode to HSB (hue,saturation,brightness) - makes it easy to color rainbows, just change the hue
  //reduce the hues available to how many circles we use
  colorMode(HSB,circles,100,100);
  //for each circle
  for (var total = 0; total < circles; total++) {
    //compute circle diameter based on reverse index (circles-total) (or max-current)
    var diameter = (circles-total) * 30;
    //change hue for each circle
    fill(total,100,100);
    //render the circle
    ellipse(x,y, diameter, diameter);
    
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

You can draw multiple groups of concentric circles, for example:

```js
var circles = 10;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  noStroke();
  colorMode(HSB,circles,100,100);
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  flower(mouseX, mouseY);
  flower(mouseX,height-mouseY);
}


var flower = function(x, y) {
  for (var total = circles-1; total >= 0; total--) {
    
    var diameter = ((20 + (total * 10)) + frameCount) % 200;
    
    fill(total,100,100);
    ellipse(x,y, diameter, diameter);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to change positions to keep the circles still somehow grouped, you could use an array to remember past positions then shift the position of each circle by one. This would get you a trails like effect, but the circles will maintain their order so will become concentric whenever the position becomes static:

```js
var circles = 48;
var diameterMin = 20;
var diameterMax = 80;
//store each circle's diameter in this array
var diameter = [];
//store each circle's position in this array
var positions = [];

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  noStroke();
  colorMode(HSB,circles-1,100,100);
  for(var i = 0; i < circles; i++){
    diameter[i] = map(i,0,circles-1,diameterMax,diameterMin);
    positions[i] = createVector(200,200);
  }
  
}
function updateCircles(){
  //copy positions backwards from last to 2nd
  for(var i = circles-1; i > 0; i--){
    positions[i].x = positions[i-1].x;
    positions[i].y = positions[i-1].y;
  }
  //set the position of the first based on mouse
  positions[i].x = mouseX;
  positions[i].y = mouseY;
}
function drawCircles(){
 for(var i = 0; i < circles; i++){
    fill(i,100,100);
    ellipse(positions[i].x,positions[i].y,diameter[i], diameter[i]);
  }
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  updateCircles();
  drawCircles();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[image: circle trails with rainbow colours]