# a for loop to repeat concentric ellipses

Tags: javascript, processing

I am struggling to figure out how to get these 2 concentric ellipses to repeat. The directions are 1) It will draw a random number of the image(this is the part I am on) and 2) Use a nested for loop such that the fill is in the outside loop and the drawing is in the inside loop. Use appropriate values. This is the original code:

```
noStroke();



for(var total = 25; total > 0; total--){

    fill(random(0,255),random(0,255), random(0,255));

    ellipse(200, 200, total * 10, total * 20);

    ellipse(200, 200, total * 20, total * 10);

}
```

This is what I have and as you can see, I got them to repeat but they have to keep their concentric detail. Getting them to keep their concentric detail is what I've been stuck on the last few days. (by concentric detail I mean the rainbow effect)

```
noStroke();

var flower = function(x,y){ 

for(var total = 5; total > 0; total--){

    fill(random(0,255),random(0,255), random(0,255));



    for(var i = 0; i < random(1,20); i++) {
    var circleX = random(x,y);
    var circleY = random(x,y);   
    ellipse(circleX, circleY, total * 10, total * 20);
    ellipse(circleX, circleY, total * 20, total * 10);

}
}
};
flower(0, 400);
```

Comment: What do you mean by you're stuck? I'm sure you aren't having any errors. Its just that you've not been able to plot those circles. aren't you?

Comment: I'm stuck in the sense that I've spent days trying to figure out how to enable the ellipses to keep their concentric detail. You're right, I am having no errors. I'm mostly asking for advice/tips to send me in the right direction.

Comment: would you mind posting a simple working code to see whats going on?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to post a snippet but it's not working. Idk. I'm pretty new to programming. How can I post working code?

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253867/using-a-for-loop-to-repeat-concentric-ellipses) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Processing.js or p5.js? You'll get better help if we can actually run your program, so try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a disconnected snippet.

It might also help if you post a mockup of what you expect this code to do versus what it's actually doing. But I think I understand your goal: you want to draw flowers by drawing concentric circles that "stack" to create an outline effect, and you want to do this a random number of times.

A couple things jump out at me:

Think about the order your loops are in. In your first snippet of code, you draw a single flower by looping `total` from `25` to `0`, and that works. Now you want to do that a random number of times. That means you want the `total` loop to be **inside** the loop that repeats a random number of times! But you've reversed this and have your random loop inside your `total` loop.

What this is telling Processing is: for a `total` of `5` times, draw a random number of circles in random locations.

Instead, what you want to do is: for a random number of times, draw a `total` of `5` circles. You also need to check where you're generating `circleX` and `circleY`. Right now every single circle is drawn in a random location, when really you want to use the same `circleX` and `circleY` for each circle that makes up the same flower. In other words you want to generate these variables before the inner loop.